# leer documents de firestore de Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift, cloud, firestore

¿Alguien sabe cómo se pueden leer la descripción del document en lugar de los campos en Cloud Firestore de Firebase?
No se como puedo leer las descripciones de del document

Para leer los campos utilizo:

```
class GetDatosDocumentoMosq: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var DatosDocumentoMosq = [ModeloTarifa1Desc]()
    
    init() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("Tarifas").addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
                    
            if let error = error {
                print("error al mostrar datos", error.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                self.DatosDocumentoMosq.removeAll()
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                    let valor = document.data()
                    let id = document.documentID
                    let Desc = valor["Desc"] as? String ?? "Sin texto"
                    let Act = valor["Act"] as? Bool ?? true

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let registros = ModeloTarifa1Desc(id: id, Desc: Desc, Act: Act)
                        self.DatosDocumentoMosq.append(registros)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
     }
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con la *descripción del document*? A los valores?

Comment: Cloud Firestore tiene colecciones, documentos y campos, el ejemplo que he puesto se muestran los campos, pero yo lo que quiero es que devuelva la despcrión de los documentos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo esta colección en Firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la función `.getDocuments`, obtienes todos los documentos:

```
db.collection("miColeccion").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
```

Compruebas que existan los documentos:

```
guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
    return
}
```

Si todo es correcto, entonces recorres los documentos y con `documentID` obtienes el nombre o la descripción:

```
for i in 0 ..< documents.count {
    let documentID = documents[i].documentID
    print("Document ID \(documentID)")
}
```

El código completo:

```
db.collection("miColeccion").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        return
    }

    for i in 0 ..< documents.count {
        let documentID = documents[i].documentID
        print("Document ID \(documentID)")
    }
}
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]